# extracting unique elements from sorted list of array

Tags: javascript, algorithm

What I have done so far:

```
var input = [1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9];

var output = [];

/*input.forEach(function(element){    // works as intended, but I know we can do better :)
    if(output.indexOf(element) == -1)
        output.push(element);
});*/

output.push(input[0]);  // first element is always unique!

for(var i=1; i<input.length; i++){  // check rest of the elements
    if(input[i] != output[i-1])
        output.push(input[i]);
}

console.log(output);
```

As you might have noticed, my logic is to check if the `i+1th` element of `input` is equal to the `ith` element of `output`, if not, add it to the `output` But, this code doesnt work. It outputs: `[1, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9]`.

What am I missing?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z22Jh/)

Comment: Oh JavaScript, in every other language you would probably have gotten an exception when trying to access an entry in a dynamic array that was not written yet..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a lot easier if you compare `input[i]` with `input[i-1]`, for example:

```
output.push(input[0]);  // first element is always unique!

for(var i=1; i<input.length; i++){  // check rest of the elements
    if(input[i] != input[i-1])  // NOTE: changed output to input
        output.push(input[i]);
}
```

This is typically how it's done, because often you don't have access to the output (for example, it's being passed on for further processing rather than being stored in an array).

Answer (score 4):

the output size is not always increasing...
it should be...

```
if(input[i]!=output[output.length-1])
```

Comment: Yes this will solve the issue, if you dont want to use output[output.length-1],you use a temp variable and save the last output value in that or just check( input[i] != input[i-1]) because its a sorted list.

Comment: use a seperate variable for if you dont want to use output[output.length-1] and increment it whenever you push an element to output

Comment: well jim's answer is perfect if you don't want to use output[output.length-1]

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the length of `output` when looking at the last item in it:

```
if(input[i] != output[output.length-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return the first item  of each value by filtering the items by the  indexOf value-

this has the advantage of not requiring the list be sorted.

```
var input = [5,9,5,3,9,3,5,1,3,9,9,1];

var output =input.filter(function(itm,i, A){
return A.indexOf(itm)==i;
});

output.sort()

/*  returned value: (Array)
1,3,5,9
*/
```